# Prove that $\sin\frac{\pi}n·\sin\frac{2\pi}n···\sin\frac{(n-1)\pi}n=\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How to prove that

> $$
> \sin\dfrac{\pi}n·\sin\dfrac{2\pi}n···\sin\dfrac{(n-1)\pi}n=\dfrac{n}{2^{n-1}}
> $$

using the roots of $(z+1)^n-1=0$?

My rough idea is to solve  $(z+1)^n-1=0$ and use **De Moivre's Theorem** to find the product of roots to prove the equality.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253739/proving-prod-k-sin-pi-k-n-n-2n-1?rq=1) might also help you.

Comment: @Ramanujan I think this question is different in the sense that OP has clearly mentioned a specific method using which he wants the answer. While in that link, neither of the answers have used the method asked by OP here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly $z=0$ is a root of $(z+1)^n-1$, so we need to exclude it to get something nontrivial for the product. Dividing and taking the limit,
$$ \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{(z+1)^n-1}{z} = n, $$
so the product of the remaining roots is $(-1)^{n-1} n$. Now we have to find expressions for the roots. We have roots
$$ z_k+1 = e^{2\pi ik/n}, \quad k \in \{1,2,\dotsc,n-1\}. $$
Therefore, rearranging and applying the formula for sine,
$$ z_k = e^{2\pi i k/n} -1 = e^{\pi i k/n} (e^{\pi i k/n}-e^{-\pi ik/n}) = e^{\pi i k/n} 2i\sin{\left( \frac{\pi k}{n} \right)}. $$

Hence, we have
$$ \begin{align}
(-1)^{n-1}n &= \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} z_k \\
&= \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} e^{\pi i( k/n+1/2)} 2\sin{\left( \frac{\pi k}{n} \right)} \\
&= 2^{n-1} \exp{\left( \pi i \left(\frac{n-1}{2}+\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k \right) \right)}  \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \sin{\left( \frac{\pi k}{n} \right)}.
\end{align} $$
The result now follows, since
$$ \exp{\left( \pi i \left(\frac{n-1}{2}+\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k\right) \right)} = \exp{\left( \pi i (n-1) \right)} = (-1)^{n-1}. $$

Comment: (+1) Well done ole sport!   And it's always nice to see you're still here.  -Mark

Answer (score 4):

Given the equation
$$(z+1)^n = 1 \tag{1}$$
Its roots are, $$z = e^{2\pi i \frac{k}{n}} - 1, \;\; 0 \leq k < n$$
Now,
$$\prod_{k = 1}^{n-1} (e^{2\pi i \frac{k}{n}} - 1)$$
is the product of all roots except $z = 0$. If you open up (1) and cancel one out of from both sides, you can take z common and the remaining polynomial will have the other roots. From Vieta's formulae, we know that,
$$\prod_{k = 1}^{n-1} (e^{2\pi i \frac{k}{n}} - 1) = (-1)^{n-1}n$$
The above can be written as,
$$\prod_{k = 1}^{n-1} e^{\pi i \frac{k}{n}}(e^{\pi i \frac{k}{n}} - e^{-\pi i \frac{k}{n}}) = (-1)^{n-1}n$$
$$\prod_{k = 1}^{n-1} e^{\pi i \frac{k}{n}}2i \sin \frac{\pi k}{n} = (-1)^{n-1}n$$
$$e^{\pi i \frac{n-1}{2}}2^{n-1}i^{n-1}\prod_{k = 1}^{n-1} \sin \frac{\pi k}{n} = (-1)^{n-1}n$$
$$\prod_{k = 1}^{n-1}\sin \frac{\pi k}{n} = \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$$